# Is there a symbol for a right arrow with a square in the middle?

Tags: symbols

I'm looking for a symbol like this [image]

Comment: Welcome! Do you have a source for the symbol? Not just out of curiosity: examples of usage may be important for inclusion in Unicode.

Comment: This symbol should be a system that processes an input signal u(t) and produces an output signal v(t). What I would like to write is: v (t) -> SquareSymbol-> u (t).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The only problem was finding a suitably small square symbol, which can be found in `mathabx` and imported.

A few tricks can make for defining also the corresponding left arrow avoiding code duplication. The square is positioned so that the distance from the arrow end to it is half than the distance to the arrow tip; this is of course reversed for the left arrow. You can vary this choice by changing `{1}{2}` into, say `{1.5}{2.5}` or whatever you think fit.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{marvosym}

\DeclareFontFamily{U}{mathb}{}
\DeclareFontShape{U}{mathb}{m}{n}{
  <-5.5> mathb5
  <5.5-6.5> mathb6
  <6.5-7.5> mathb7
  <7.5-8.5> mathb8
  <8.5-9.5> mathb9
  <9.5-11> mathb10
  <11-> mathb12
}{}
\DeclareSymbolFont{mathb}{U}{mathb}{m}{n}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\abxsmallsquare}{2}{mathb}{"05}

\makeatletter
\DeclareRobustCommand{\sqrightarrow}{%
  \mathrel{\mathpalette\sq@arrow{{1}{2}\rightarrow}}%
}
\DeclareRobustCommand{\sqleftarrow}{%
  \mathrel{\mathpalette\sq@arrow{{2}{1}\leftarrow}}%
}
\newcommand{\sq@arrow}[2]{\sq@@arrow#1#2}
\newcommand{\sq@@arrow}[4]{%
  \ooalign{%
    \hskip 0pt plus #2fil
    $\m@th#1\abxsmallsquare$%
    \hskip 0pt plus #3fil\cr
    $\m@th#1#4$\cr}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

$a\sqrightarrow b \sqleftarrow c$

$\scriptstyle a\sqrightarrow b \sqleftarrow c$

$\scriptscriptstyle a\sqrightarrow b \sqleftarrow c$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 8):

Two variant solution based on the `stackinset`  command from `stackengine` and `relsize` or `rotating`:

```
\documentclass[border = 2pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{stackengine} %
\usepackage{amssymb, relsize, rotating}
\usepackage{old-arrows} 
\newcommand\sqarrow{\stackMath\mathrel{\stackinset{c}{0ex}{c}{0.14ex}{\mathsmaller{\mathsmaller{\Box}}}{ ―――→ }}}
\newcommand\varsqarrow{\stackMath\mathrel{\stackinset{c}{0ex}{c}{0.12ex}{\rotatebox{45}{$ \diamond $}}{ ―――→ }}}
\begin{document}

 $ A \sqarrow B$ \quad

$ A \varsqarrow B$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @egreg: Probably a freudian slip… Actually I thought \mathrel. I'll fix that in a second. Thank you for pointing it!